# Wix Installer Is Copying a File During Build Instead of Install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a kind of strange issue that I've never run into before. I have a Wix installer that has the following fragment/component:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="groupID">
       <Component Id="componentID" Guid="a guid" Directory="a directory defined elsewhere">
            <File Id="fileID" Source="$(var.mylibraryname.TargetPath)"/>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup >
</Fragment>
```

The issue is that the file defined above gets copied into the DirectoryRef when I *build* the Wix project, but it does *not* copy over when I install it. I do this type of thing pretty frequently, but have never seen this issue crop up. Why would Wix copy the file while being built? In every other instance , running the MSI does.

Comment: Do you have `Compressed="yes"` for the `Package` element? WiX copies uncompressed files into the layout. To diagnose the install issue is, look at verbose log (`msiexec -i YourSetup.msi -l*vx LogFile.txt`)

Comment: zett, I do, yes.

Comment: Try using [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) during the build to see which process is doing that and while what command line arguments.

Comment: If this is a Visual Studio project: maybe right-click the WiX project in Visual Studio => Properties => Build Events. Is there anything there? Hard to know what it is without seeing the full source. You could put it on [github.com](https://www.github.com) and we can have a look?